# How to allow utm_source & utm_medium in IIS Rewrite / Reverse Proxy

Tags: iis, server, url-rewriting, web-config, odoo

I have created reverse proxy Windows server 2016 and IIS.

Everything is working fine, but the problem is following it doesnt allow the url like this,

`https://mywebsite/shop/product/3231?utm_source=IGShopping&utm_medium=Social`

but when I replace `utm_source` as `utm_sour` or something then it works fine.

In simple words, with `utm_source` and `utm_medium` variables it gives this error.
[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSuzo.png)

Directly with the localhost it works fine.
`https://mywebsite/shop/product/3231?utm_source=IGShopping&utm_medium=Social`

For the reference, my web.config file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>

            <outboundRules>
            
            
                <clear />

      <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="No SameSite">

        <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />

        <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=None; Secure" />

      </rule>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyOutboundRule1" preCondition="ResponseIsHtml1" enabled="true">
                    <match filterByTags="A, Form, Img" pattern="^http(s)?://localhost:8068/(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" value="http{R:1}://mocauae.ae/{R:2}" />
                </rule>
                <preConditions>
                    <preCondition name="ResponseIsHtml1">
                        <add input="{RESPONSE_CONTENT_TYPE}" pattern="^text/html" />
                    </preCondition>
                    
                    <preCondition name="No SameSite">

          <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />

          <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=None; Secure" negate="true" />

        </preCondition>
                    
                    
                </preConditions>
                
            </outboundRules>
            <rules>
                <rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="http://localhost:8068/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="HTTPS" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://localhost:8068" redirectType="Found" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="HTTPS force" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
 <match url="(.*)" />
 <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
 </conditions>
 <action type="Redirect" url="https://localhost:8068" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
 </rule>
                <rule name="https pure" enabled="false" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://localhost:8068" redirectType="Found" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
        <httpRedirect enabled="false" destination="http://localhost:8068" exactDestination="true" />
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I the solution by just simply ignoring the url parameter and it worked for me

```
<rule name="IngnoreUTMSource" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="utm_source=.*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```